# How to set up a functional macro with parameters in C++?

Tags: c++

is there a way that I can make this work? Or do I need to use separate files?

```
#include <iostream>                                                     // Necessary 
using namespace std;
#define long double mMaxOf2(long double min, long double max)
#define long double mMaxOf3(long double Min, long double Max, long double Mid)\
{\
     mMaxOf2(mMaxOf2((Min), (Mid), (Max)));\
}

int main()
{
    double primary;
    double secondary;
    double tertiary;
    cout << "Please enter three numbers: ";
    cin >> primary >> secondary >> tertiary;
    cout << "The maximum of " << primary << " " << secondary << " " << tertiary;
    cout << " using mMaxOf3 is " << (mMaxOf3(primary, secondary, tertiary));


    return 0;
}
```

Problem lies with mMaxOf3, it isn't declared... Hmm maybe I need the prototype.

Comment: The homework tag is not to be added to any new questions.  You should have seen the big note under it as you tried to add it.

Comment: If possible (as it will always may be), don't use macros. Use either inline functions if you want macro-like performance benefits (or just let the compiler optimize).

Comment: Sorry, must have missed that about the homework tag.

Comment: You should fix the parenthesises in MaxOf3. And think how you would choose the MaxOf2, the macro is just empty now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi line macros require a \ character at the end of each line (except the last).

Answer (score 1):

Using macros is discouraged. Use functions instead. Unless this is a homework assignment that specifically wants you to write macros. In that case, you should know that macros are based on rather simple text substitution. They are not aware of types and they don't have a scope (which is why they shouldn't be used). For example, a function that determines the max of two integers:

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

However, a macro that does the same doesn't know anything about `int`s and doesn't have a scope nor does `return` mean anything for a macro:

```
#define max(a, b) (a > b ? a : b)
```

Using that macro means that the preprocessor will simply replace your text with the macro's definition. For example, if you write this:

```
max(3, 5);
```

the preprocessor will transform that text into this:

```
(3 > 5 ? 3 : 5)
```

and that's it. No types, no scope, just a plain copy&paste of text. You could just as well have written:

```
max(if, else);
```

and the preprocessor would still happily transform that into:

```
(if > else ? if : else)
```

which makes zero sense. It doesn't check it, and it doesn't care. It just deals with text. I hope this makes it clear now why something like:

```
#define long double mMaxOf2(long double min, long double max)
```

cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 things wrong:

1. Macros must be declared in one line so you have to separate lines with a backslash ( \ )
2. Macros can't return values either, so the "return" there is not going to do what you want.

You should think of macros like copy/paste's.